# Куда ставиться homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

Ставлю ларавел по документации используя vagrant box add laravel/homestead. Homestead поставился, но не понятно куда он поставился, директория какая. Я на линуксе. Я так понял он глобально что ли поставился? Раньше ставил с помощью git в этот раз решил попробовать этот способ. Подскажите где искать установленный homestead таким способом

Comment: Отказался от Homestead, постоянно какие-то проблемы вылазили. Посмотрите на [WSL2, Docker, Sail](https://docs.rularavel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

## Пошагово

- Установить `vagrant` & `virtualbox`
- Добавить бокс: `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`
- Склонировать репу: `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead`
- Произвести инит: `cd ~/Homestead && bash init.sh`
- Скопить конфиг: `cp ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml.example ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml`

**Пример конфига**

```yml
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

folders:
  - map: ~/projects/test-homestaed
    to: /home/vagrant/test-homestaed

sites:
  - map: test-homestaed.loc
    to: /home/vagrant/test-homestaed
    type: apache
    php: "7.4"

databases:
  - test_homestaed
```

- Добавить хост в `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.10.10 test-homestaed.loc
```

- Запустить: `cd ~/Homestead && vagrant up`

Comment: установка через git это второй способ, который не нужен если используешь первый. Вы хоть почитайте документацию то. Это два разных способа. Тут либо добавляешь бокс, либо клонируешь репу. И судя по всему первый способ ставить homestead глобально. Только не знаю куда это ставиться в таком случае. В случае с git он локально ставиться в ту директорию из которой был сделан git clone

Comment: Я по докам вообще-то и делал)) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#installation-and-setup